# How can I compress a markov transition probability matrix?

Tags: math, matrix, hidden-markov-models

I'm performing a simple experiment. I have a markov transition matrix and I need to know how to compute a transition similarity matrix using spears algorithm. I'm following this paper(pages 8 and 9)

http://oro.open.ac.uk/2963/4/hong.pdf

I understand how to get the graph, the original probability matrix but I don't know how the original matrix gets converted to the transition similarity matrix.

Anyone can explain?

[Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06lf2.png)

Comment: Perhaps http://math.stackexchange.com/ would be a better fit for this question.

Comment: Do you mean compress or compute?

Comment: @samgak I see from the paper that indeed "compress" is intended. The transition matrix in question may be very large, so the goal is to find a low-rank approximation to it.

Comment: @pau-muñoz To compute a similarity matrix for a very large matrix, take a look at ARPACK, a package for computing eigenvalues and eigenvectors for very large matrices.